# Cannot map HTTP response to interface type in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am calling a HTTP request and typecasting the received response to required type using an interface, in a service. The HTTP response is a JSON object with some key value pair of items. I have subscribed to that service in an component. When I console log the response received in the subscribe function, it logs the object perfectly with key value pair. But when I assign that object to the component class member, it does not seem to be typecast to the required interface type. Because when I use the class member variable keys in the component html, I get error - 'Cannot read property 'X' of undefined'

Here are the code snippets -

Interface

```
export interface NewsItem {
    status: string;
    totalResults: number;
    articles: any[];
}
```

Service

```
export class NewsService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    getCategoryNews(): Observable<NewsItem>{
        return this.http.get<NewsItem>(newsUrl);
    }
}
```

component.ts

```
export class NewsContainerComponent implements OnInit {
newsData: NewsItem;
constructor(private _newsService: NewsService) {}
ngOnInit() {
        this._newsService.getCategoryNews().subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.newsData = response;
                console.log(this.newsData);
            },
            (err) => {
                console.error(err);
            }
        )
    }
}
```

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of newsData.articles">
    {{item.description}}
</div>
```

Actual Response from the HTTP request is as follows

```
{
   "status":"ok",
   "totalResults":2,
   "articles":[
      {
         "source":{
            "id":"google-news-au",
            "name":"Google News (Australia)"
         },
         "title":"Former Malaysian PM questioned on graft",
         "description":"Former Malaysian Prime Minister Najib Razak could face criminal charges after being questioned over a corruption scandal."
      },
      {
         "source":{
            "id":"the-guardian-uk",
            "name":"The Guardian (UK)"
         },
         "title":"Manchester Arena attack: thousands to mark anniversary",
         "description":"Series of events across city including a mass singalong are being held one year on from terrorist attack",
      }
   ]
}
```

In case of above code, I am getting error - "Cannot read property 'articles' of undefined". Why I am getting this error even when type casting HTTP response with interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the data before it is Resolved
In this case Use [**safe navigation operator ( ?. )**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) 
While accessing properties of an object it may throw an exception if the object is null or undefined. The Angular safe navigation operator `(?.)` is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="newsData">
    <div *ngFor="let item of newsData?.articles">
        {{item.description}}
    </div>
<ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the safe navigation operator is introduced in angular and was not there in angularjs, right? By the way, angularjs does not have any issue while using properties undefined objects in template, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use safe navigation operator `?` for your use case like below used in code -

```
<div *ngFor="let item of newsData?.articles">
    {{item.description}}
</div>
```

safe navigation operator `?` operator in Angular which avoids any errors to be thrown in case of parent/base value does not exist onto your application, and also very useful in case of async binding

Comment: @Pradeep, thanks. I think you cannot intialize fields in an interface, so  writing 'articles: any[] = []' in an interface is not possible as I have checked it. But writing 'newsData?.articles' in ngFor removed the error. But can you please explain about this? What exactly the '?' operator does in this case? Also, Do i need to this for all fields of the object (newsData) if I use them in the template? Doesn't the HTTP response  cast to the interface type at first place?

Comment: ?. can be used to soak up null references in a chain of properties. Use it instead of the dot accessor . in cases where the base value may be null or undefined.

Comment: @AbhinandanKhilari I am not sure about `intialize filed in interface`, But yes `?` called as safe navigation operator in Angular which avoid any errors to be thrown in case of parent/base value is not existed onto you application, and also very usefull in case of async binding.

Comment: @user1608841 yes well exaplained !!